# IE8/Compat View Bug - All images stack on each other at top of Div. Need Help

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

A very strange behavior is occuring on the website I'm working on in a animal display list.

The animals are laid out in a grid format.  When in IE8 and with compat mode turned on, the animals pictures all shoot to the top of the screen and stack under each other.

This is completely perplexing to me.  I need to call upon the talent of this community to help me fix this bug.

Example Page found here - http://www.petango.com/Forms/AnimalSearchResults.aspx?z=L2R%205W3&d=2147483647&sh=0&s=1&b=650&g=All&size=All&c=All&a=All&dec=All&p=False&sid=0&zs=True&ht=False

In IE8, it looks okay, when compat mode is turned on, the images shoot to the top of the page.  I can only assume this behavior is found in IE7.

I'm at a loss at where to start troubleshooting this.

[image]

**UPDATE 1 - 12:16PM**

I tried a test where I took the animal display code and removed the unordered list and replaced it with a table.

[image]

The Div within the LI element doesn't seem to be the culprit?

Comment: Thinking out loud(or in text), try a conditional statement targeting IE 7, and try giving either a display: inline-block or height: 1% to the parent of each parent cell holding a pet(.asr-wrap-animal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certianly you need to clean up your markup and not use a `<ul>` and `<li>` structure with all the nested `<divs>` when a simple `<table>` would do nicely.

Also, you can get a little closer by changing `div.center-photo-box-1` to have `position:relative` instead of `static`.  that will get you closer...

Comment: Not only did change it to relative get me closer, it completely fixed the behavior, well done.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have `<div>` inside `<li>`. I would also get your page to have fewer errors when you validate it at [validator.w3.org](http://validator.w3.org).

Comment: There's a lot of functionality within the image Div which as has many CSS selectors that repeatedly point to that div - specifically there is some css that allows the image to align vert/hori center no matter what the dimensions are.  There is also the Video Icon that also positions itself relative to the size of the image.

Should I just get rid of the unordered list and use a table and apply css class to each row instead?

Comment: A table would help as you have a strict grid-like layout.

Answer (score 0):

check the site in ie7 - compatability mode is flakey and not always an accurate reflection of older versions of ie.

IF you find that it is just compatibility mode causing the problem yon can save yourself having to make changes by simply telling ie to not allow compatibility mode using the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```